# Is there a way to randomly assign routes or roles for a defined number of actors in Akka?

Tags: scala, cluster-computing, akka, actor

Suppose I want to implement a cluster system where some actos will be request dispatchers and others will be standard nodes. How can I randomly assign a predefined number of actors (does not matter the hostname and port) a specific route or even role?

Explaining better:

Suppose I have these nodes:

```
1 - akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@192.168.0.1:2551/user/clusterListener
2 - akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@192.168.0.2:2552/user/clusterListener
3 - akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@192.168.0.3:2553/user/clusterListener
4 - akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@192.168.0.4:2554/user/clusterListener
```

Now I want 2 of them to have the sub route "dispatcher" (akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx/user/clusterListener/dispatcher)

Comment: Not sure about the random part, but otherwise you could add something to the configuration of these nodes and use that to decide if the actors are to be started or not. Cluster role configuration might be useful for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3.0/contrib/cluster-singleton.html for coordination.

Every actor without role may send "GetRole" message to the singleton and it will pickup role randomly (using some internal RoleMap). Note that you should listen memberDown message from singleton to free role when some node (obtained this role) has removed.

Comment: also you should restore RoleMap (by broadcasting CheckRole from singleton) after singleton failure.